# In igraph how can I replace 1 node of a network with a node from another network?

Tags: r, igraph

I have a graph like the following:

```
 set.seed(12)
 net <- sample_gnp(20, 1/4)
 V(net)$male <- sample(c(0, 1), vcount(net), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.5, 0.5))

 graph <- sample_gnp(50, 1/5)
 V(net)$male <- sample(c(0, 1), vcount(graph), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.7))
```

How can I take a node from the network, "graph" and replace it with a node from the network "net"? I tried the following and it told me it was invalid syntax:

```
 V(net)[1] <- V(graph)[24]
```

What I want to happen is that following whatever correct line of code, 
V(net)[1]$male will return the same values as V(graph)[24]$male and more attributes should they exist.

Comment: @d.b Does that replace all aspects of the node? (ie. will the new node have the attribute values of node 24?)

Comment: @d.b I clarified my desired output in an edit.

Comment: Try `vertex.attributes(net, 1) = vertex.attributes(graph, 24)`